# How to calculate bit rate of video?

Tags: ios, iphone, video, video-processing, bitrate

In iPhone developing video compress functionality. I developed that features but little bit confusion about bit rate calculation.

I m using bellow methods for video compress.

```
 1. AVAsset 
 2. AVAssetTrack
 3. AVAssetWriterInput
 4. AVAssetWriter
 5. AVAssetReader
 6. AVAssetReaderOutput
 7. AVAssetTrack
 8. AVAssetReader
```

Can we get video bit rate of original video?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18199018/programatically-get-the-bitrate-of-an-audio-file                                    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159663/how-to-get-specific-information-about-media-files-duration-bitrate-fps-etc

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929825/how-can-i-read-the-properties-of-an-audio-file-in-objective-c-for-ios

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the tracks of AVAsset, determine what kind of track it is (audio/video) and use "estimatedDataRate" property of AVAssetTrack to get the average bitrate of file. Something like this:

```
AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:url];
for(AVAssetTrack *track in asset.tracks)
{
    if([track.mediaType isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo])
    {
        videoBitrate = track.estimatedDataRate;
    }
    if([track.mediaType isEqual:AVMediaTypeAudio])
    {
        audioBitrate = track.estimatedDataRate;
    }
}
```